# Multithread task or not?

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I don't know if it's worth using multithreading for the following task.  It reads an input file and for every line, it reads a table in the DB and checks if the record exists (with the same id), then add or update the record in that table.

I can:

1. use a single thread which read and write to database sequentially, line by line
2. use a multithread: more threads will do the same work adding or updating more lines at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're not establishing a new DB connection for each operation!

Comment: If you don't know if its worth multithreading, you clearly don't need to do multithreading. Once you _do_ know for sure (i.e. you run into performance issues), then do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience is reading files with multiple threads not faster than reading the file in one thread. I won't expect it to be faster.

Writing to a database will be faster, if you use `PreparedStatements` and batch-updates.

I don't think multiple threads will speed it up, I would bet, that it will slow down the write performance, because of multiple transactions.

But there is only one valid answer:
**Measure it**

And if you don't have a performance issue, don't try to fix one. this will lead to worse code.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm developing a java task, but I don't know if it's worth using multithreading.

The answers depends a lot on the performance of your database system.  If it has IO bandwidth to spare then multithreading may help.  But chances are it is IO bound.  Even if you added multiple threads to the problem they may just be waiting for database IO bandwidth and not perform much concurrent execution.  You might spending programming time doing the conversion to only see a marginal, if any, speed improvement.

You probably would get a lot more performance boost by moving your database to a SSD drive than spending time threading your lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for Springs batch update( if you can use spring) it is pretty simple and there are lots of scaling options. I had similar requirement. I had used two different approaches
 The first one.
  Read a file line by line and save it in list till some limit is reached say 10000, once the limit is reached create a thread and pass on the list. which use to validate the data and write to file(individual thread use to write to file).once all operations done I use to call sql loader.

1. reading a file can't be done using multi threading(If you do
   also there will not be any difference performance).
2. Multi threading id useful if you have lots of validation before
   writing to DB.
3. You connection pool should be always greater than number of threads
4. Though SQL loader gave me significance performance, The write ammount of chunk of data will give the performance else time consumed for spawning thread will be more then actual execution of business logic

The other Approach I used was Spring batch
Which Reads chunk of data from the file prepares the statement and does an bulk load. as simple to code. There is difference in performance.

Why can't you read all the data from db(yes its memory consuming) and validate your data while preparing statement( and decide insert /update)  rather than than having multiple db call